# Как заставить GameObject двигаться за курсором

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть простая сцена, на ней есть камера и GameObject. Мне нужно, чтобы GameObject двигался за курсором мыши(обьект должно распологался строго под курсором). Как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения](Где белая точка - курсор, а под ним должен находиться обьект. При перемещении курсора обьект должен следовать за ним)

Я конечно пытался реализовать это через Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint, но к сожалению ничего не получилось.

Comment: "Двигался" это поворачиваться в сторону мышки или идти за ней?

Comment: @Арман, что бы он шел за ней

Comment: ```gameObject.transform.position = Input.mousePosition```

Comment: Но там осторожнее: левая часть - Vector3, правая часть - Vector2

Comment: @Арман, я наверно плохо изьяснился. Я обновил вопрос... Есть камера(она одна) и в пределах ее видимости нужно заставить следовать обьект за курсором.

Comment: Я именно на этот вопрос и ответил. Координаты вашего объекта можно узнать с помощью `gameObject.transform.position` а координаты мышки `Input.mousePosition`. Если вы попробовали это и не получилось то скажите конкретно что. Есть ещё вариант с Raycast, но это не советую.